# Unity mvc A single instance of controller '' cannot be used to handle multiple requests

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have a MVC 5 application. I'm using Unity as my DI.
In my application I have Controller with two actions:

- Main Action
- Child Action

My main Action view calling Html.RenderAction("ChildAction").

I get next error:

```
A single instance of controller '' cannot be used to handle multiple requests. If a custom controller factory is in use, make sure that it creates a new instance of the controller for each request.
```

I tryed many solutions such creating custom "UnityControllerFactory":

```
  public class UnityControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    IUnityContainer container;

    public UnityControllerFactory(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public override IController CreateController(RequestContext context, string controllerName)
    {
        Type type = GetControllerType(context, controllerName);

        if (type == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Could not find a controller with the name {0}", controllerName));
        }



        return (IController)container.Resolve(type);
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext reqContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        IController controller;
        if (controllerType == null)
            throw new HttpException(
                    404, String.Format(
                        "The controller for path '{0}' could not be found" +
        "or it does not implement IController.",
                    reqContext.HttpContext.Request.Path));

        if (!typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(controllerType))
            throw new ArgumentException(
                    string.Format(
                        "Type requested is not a controller: {0}",
                        controllerType.Name),
                        "controllerType");
        try
        {
            controller = container.Resolve(controllerType)
                            as IController;


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format(
                                    "Error resolving controller {0}",
                                    controllerType.Name), ex);
        }
        return controller;
    }
    public override void ReleaseController(IController controller)
    {
        container.Teardown(controller);
    }
```

Register the controller with "TransientLifetimeManager":

```
container.RegisterType<TestController>(new TransientLifetimeManager());
```

Nothing worked.

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you calling `base.GetControllerInstance` after the call to `container.Resolve`?

Comment: Sorry, wrong code copy, it's leftovers from previous tests. I removed this line